# jQuery/JS load content before document ready

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm searching for a solution (jQuery or plain JS) that allows loading HTML/JS-Content into a given DIV before(!) DOM is loaded completely.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var mywidth = $(window).width();
if(mywidth > 1000) {
$("#mydiv").load("some_html_with_external_javascript.html");
}
});
```

This works fine - of course. But if the loaded content contains external JS, the JS-Content is not executed. I need something like a mix of JS and PHP, something like:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<script>
var mywidth = $(window).width();
if(mywidth > 1000) {
// <?php require_once "some_html_with_external_javascript.html"; ?>
}
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a soloution in jQuery / JS or JS / PHP?

Comment: @Epodax I'm searching for a solution in jQuery or plain JS
EDIT: A solution in PHP is just interesting when there is a function to give PHP the information about current window-width and window-height while document is loading.

Comment: look to [$.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) and `document.write`

Comment: You could make a synchronous ajax request in the head of the page but that would have a very negative effect on the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) in order to do that. Just insert a new script tag at the current position, which is executed before the next (script) tags (very similar to the php code). According to your question, the requested script is loaded synchronously.

**index.html:**

```
<script>
console.log("first")
document.write('<script src="second.js"><\/script>')
</script>
<script>
console.log("third")
</script>
```

**second.js:**

```
console.log("second")
```

The browser console will load *second.js* first before logging "third". The output is therefore, as expected:

- "first"
- "second"
- "third"

I want to add that synchronous loading should be avoided, if possible. This is a huge performance bottleneck.